# Java Mouse After a Drag

Tags: java

I'm making a small game project in Java. In it you have a character that shoots in the direction of the mouse when "pressed" or "dragged" (you know, in Java's terms). The only problem is that if you stop dragging but you still hold the left mouse button down you stop shooting.

Is there a way to detect if the mouse button is down after a drag?

**NOTE:** the mouse is not sensed as "pressed" after the drag.

Comment: What do you mean by "drag"? Can you post the specific property you're talking about?

Comment: Can you please provide some code? Are you using a Canvas object, Swing or any other API?

Comment: You will have a mouse pressed and released event associated with button, y should be able to detect when the use presses the button and releases it

Comment: Check the documentation on `MouseMotionListener`, which has `mouseDragged()` and so on

Comment: look at this [java game development](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL210C2267A8922854)

Answer (score 3):

You will get the information when a mouse button is pressed and when it is released again. If you want to know the state in between, you need to use a boolean to store that information.

Example:

```
final boolean[] buttonStates = new boolean[3];

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
  buttonStates[e.getButton()] = true;
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
  buttonStates[e.getButton()] = false;
}
```

You would do the same for keyboard input by the way.